# Plotting a Tuple in Python

Tags: python

In python, what is the syntax that will let me plot a tuple such as

```
t = [(9,2,5),(3,6,4),(2,8,4)]
```

I am having trouble since there are three elements in each combination.

Comment: are you using some plotting library e.g. matplotlib?

Comment: What is form of your plot?

Comment: Yes, I am using matplotlib.pyplot

Comment: What do you mean by "plotting a tuple"? What should it look like if you plotted `t` on a piece of paper?

Comment: What is your desired output? A point in the 3-d space?

Answer (score 1):

If your t means: (x,y,z) => (9, 3, 2), (2, 6, 8), (5, 4, 4)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

data = [(9, 3, 2), (2, 6, 8), (5, 4, 4)]
x, y, z = data[0], data[1], data[2]
ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='3d')
total_point = len(data)
ax.scatter(x[:total_point], y[:total_point], z[:total_point], c='red')
ax.plot(x[:total_point], y[:total_point], z[:total_point], c='yellow')

ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_xlabel('X')
plt.show()
```

output:
[image]

Comment: I tried running that but then I get this error: "shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape"

Comment: That's because `scatter()` requires the length of each variable to must be the same.

Comment: check your data. each tuple length must be the same.

Comment: the x,y,z variables point to the tuple slice position.  :total_point returns the range of tuples in the list.